# How to convert timestamp column to epoch seconds?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, timestamp, apache-spark-sql

How do you convert a timestamp column to epoch seconds?

```
var df = sc.parallelize(Seq("2018-07-01T00:00:00Z")).toDF("date_string")
df = df.withColumn("timestamp", $"date_string".cast("timestamp"))
df.show(false)
```

DataFrame:

```
+--------------------+---------------------+
|date_string         |timestamp            |
+--------------------+---------------------+
|2018-07-01T00:00:00Z|2018-07-01 00:00:00.0|
+--------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have a timestamp you can cast it to a long to get the epoch seconds

```
df = df.withColumn("epoch_seconds", $"timestamp".cast("long"))
df.show(false)
```

DataFrame

```
+--------------------+---------------------+-------------+
|date_string         |timestamp            |epoch_seconds|
+--------------------+---------------------+-------------+
|2018-07-01T00:00:00Z|2018-07-01 00:00:00.0|1530403200   |
+--------------------+---------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: other option:  df = df.withColumn("epoch_seconds", df.timestamp.cast("long"))

Answer (score 7):

Use [`unix_timestamp`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#unix_timestamp(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) from `org.apache.spark.functions`. It can a timestamp column or from a string column where it is possible to specify the format. From the documentation:

> ```
> public static Column unix_timestamp(Column s)
> ```
>
> Converts time string in format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss to Unix timestamp (in seconds), using the default timezone and the default locale, return null if fail.
>
> ```
> public static Column unix_timestamp(Column s, String p)
> ```
>
> Convert time string with given pattern (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) to Unix time stamp (in seconds), return null if fail.

Use as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.functions._

df.withColumn("epoch_seconds", unix_timestamp($"timestamp")))
```

or if the column is a string with other format:

```
df.withColumn("epoch_seconds", unix_timestamp($"date_string", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")))
```

Comment: This shifts the seconds count to the server's local timezone for me.

Answer (score 4):

It can be easily done with `unix_timestamp` function in spark SQL like this:

```
spark.sql("SELECT unix_timestamp(inv_time) AS time_as_long FROM agg_counts LIMIT 10").show()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `unix_timestamp` and cast it into any datatype.

Example:

```
val df1 = df.select(unix_timestamp($"date_string", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").cast(LongType).as("epoch_seconds"))
```